# Calculating IRR (Internal Rate of Return) in Ruby using recursion

Tags: ruby, finance

Is there a way to improve this code? (specially how I built the recursion and the breaking out of the loops and conditionals)

```
# Returns sum of present value of a sequence of cash flows  
# rate = interest rate (month)
# initial amount = balance at the beginning
# *amounts = sequence of cash flows (1 or more)

def present_value_of_series(rate, initial_amount, *amounts)
  present_value = initial_amount
  i = 0
  while i < amounts.length
    present_value += amounts[i] / ( (1+rate)**(i+1) )
    present_value
    i +=1   
  end
  return present_value
end


# Returns the IRR (Internal Rate of Return) for a sequence of cash flows
#
# IRR definition: the IRR is the rate at which the present value of a sequence of cash flows equals zero (or close to zero). It is reached by trial and error, using the steps below:
#
# 1. Define lower limit and upper limit for the rate - this is the range that will be tested
# 2. Define the rate increment at each iteration
# 3. Calculate the present value of a sequence of cash flows starting at the lower limit and keep incrementing according to defined increment
# 4. When the present value found is below zero, it means that a new lower and upper limit have been found
# 5. Increase calculation precision using a recursive function, this time incrementing at 10x more finer increments.


def irr(lower_guess, higher_guess, increment, *amounts)
  rate = lower_guess
  precision_level = 1
  while rate <= higher_guess
    if present_value_of_series(rate, *amounts) < 0
      if present_value_of_series(rate, *amounts) >= -precision_level
        #debug puts "present value = #{present_value_of_series(rate, *amounts)}"
        puts "rate = #{rate}"
        puts "rate = #{(rate*100).round(2)}% (rounded)"
        # returns annual rate
        annual_rate = (1+rate)**12-1
        puts "annual rate = #{annual_rate}"
        puts "annual rate = #{(annual_rate*100).round(2)}% (rounded)"
        break
      else
        irr((rate-increment), rate, increment/10, *amounts)
        break
      end
    else
      rate += increment
    end
  end
end

# Usage Example:
# 30000 loan to be paid in 12 installments of different values
# lower_guess = 0.005 (0.5%)
# higher_guess = 0.5 (50%)
# increment = 0.01 (1%)

puts irr(0.005, 0.50, 0.01, -30000.00, 2986.55, 2954.11, 2921.68, 2889.25, 2856.82, 2824.38, 2791.94, 2759.51, 2727.07, 2694.65, 2662.21, 2629.77)
```

Answer (score 3):

- Sanity checking
  You should probably add some sanity checks. It's entirely possible to provide a range that'll *never* produce a result.
- Separate output from calculation
  Your test code ends up printing an extra blank line because `#irr` doesn't actually return anything. It'd be nicer to let `#irr` actually return the rate it found; you can do whatever you want with it afterward. Right now it just prints.
- Too many splats
  Variadic arguments are neat, but aren't really that necessary here. It'd be simpler and more straightforward to pass an actual array for the amounts.
- Repetition
  No need to do call `present_value_of_series` two-three times in a row, like you do here:

  ```
  if present_value_of_series(rate, *amounts) < 0
    if present_value_of_series(rate, *amounts) >= -precision_level
      #debug puts "present value = #{present_value_of_series(rate, amounts)}"
  ```

  Just stick it in a variable.
- `#present_value_of_series`
  This can be simplified by *not* treating the initial value as a separate argument, and using `#reduce` to do the sum:

  ```
  def present_value_of_series(rate, amounts)
    amounts.each_with_index.reduce(0) do |sum, (amount, index)|
      sum + amount / (rate + 1)**index
    end
  end
  ```

  Note that this also matches your other code where you *do* treat the amounts as an array. No need for `*` splats.

  As a general note, you rarely need `while` or `for` loops when iterating arrays in Ruby. There's almost always a neater way.
- `#irr`
  Since you're dealing with a range, it'd be nice to use, well, a `Range`. A range also gives you a `#step` iterator, which is useful here.

Here's what I came up with. It works the same as yours (recursion), but I can't say I'm super happy with it - `return`ing from inside the `#detect` block feel wrong, but it avoids recalculating the present value afterward to check it against `-1`.

```
def irr(range, step, amounts)
  rate = range.step(step).detect do |rate|
    present_value = present_value_of_series(rate, amounts)
    if present_value < 0
      return rate if present_value >= -1
      true
    end
  end

  if rate.nil?
    raise "No solution"
  else
    irr((rate-step..rate), step / 10, amounts)
  end
end
```

Still needs extra sanity checks, though.

A possible optimization (trading some memory for computation) would be to use [`Array#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) instead of `#detect`. It does however mean that the range has to be made into an array first (e.g. `range.step(step).to_a.bsearch ...`).

Speaking of binary searching, you could also do:

```
def irr(min_rate, max_rate, amounts)
  range = max_rate - min_rate
  raise "No solution" if range <= Float::EPSILON * 2

  rate = range.fdiv(2) + min_rate
  present_value = present_value_of_series(rate, amounts)

  if present_value > 0
    irr(rate, max_rate, amounts)
  elsif present_value < -1
    irr(min_rate, rate, amounts)
  else
    rate
  end
end
```

Basic idea is that it keeps guessing in the direction of the answer by testing a rate midway between `min_rate` and `max_rate`. It gives up if the difference between `min_rate` and `max_rate` would introduce floating point precision loss.

It's the fastest solution of the bunch, though it could perhaps be smarter about checking the initial min/max before starting the iteration (it could do that up front by calculating present values for max and min, and only then, if the range makes sense, handle the iteration in separate method). It should probably have a `precision` argument as well, but that's trivial.